# has_one through relation to polymorphic model using custom type and foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

We had two apps with similar database tables, but under different names. Now we have merged the two databases into one, keeping tables in different schemas.

So now we have the following models and tables:

```rb
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  has_one(
    :portal_account,
    class_name: 'Portal::Account',
    foreign_key: :external_profile_id,
    dependent: :restrict_with_exception,
  )
end
```

table: `public.profiles`

| id | portal_account_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 |
| 2 | 22 |
| 3 | 33 |

---

```rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_one(
    :portal_item,
    class_name: 'Portal::Item',
    foreign_key: :external_product_id,
    dependent: :restrict_with_exception,
  )
end
```

table: `public.products`

| id | portal_item_id |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 44 |
| 5 | 55 |
| 6 | 66 |

---

```rb
module Portal
  class Account < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name_prefix = 'portal.'
  end
end
```

table: `portal.accounts`

| id | external_profile_id |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 1 |
| 22 | 2 |
| 33 | 3 |

---

```rb
module Portal
  class Item < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name_prefix = 'portal.'

    belongs_to :assignable, polymorphic: true
  end
end
```

table: `portal.items`

| id | external_product_id | assignable_id | assignable_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 44 | 4 | 11 | 'Account' |
| 55 | 5 | xx | 'Group' |
| 66 | 6 | yy | 'Group' |

---

I need to add a one-to-one relation `portal_item_profile`: from `Product` to `Profile` through `Portal::Item`. I tried to do it this way:

```rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_one(
    :portal_item,
    class_name: 'Portal::Item',
    foreign_key: :external_product_id,
    dependent: :restrict_with_exception,
  )

  # new relation:
  has_one(
    :portal_item_profile,
    through: :portal_item,
    class_name: 'Profile',
    foreign_key: :portal_account_id,
    source: :assignable,
    source_type: 'Account',
  )
end
```

But the SQL generated by `Product.find(4).portal_item_profile` is incorrect:

```
SELECT "profiles".*
FROM "profiles"
    INNER JOIN "portal"."items"
        ON "profiles"."id" = "portal"."items"."assignable_id"
WHERE "portal"."items"."external_product_id" = 4
    AND "portal"."items"."assignable_type" = 'Account'
LIMIT 1
```

The correct query should look like this:

```
SELECT "profiles".*
FROM "profiles"
    INNER JOIN "portal"."items"
        ON "profiles"."portal_account_id" = "portal"."items"."assignable_id"
        AND "portal"."items"."assignable_type" = 'Account'
WHERE "portal"."items"."external_product_id" = 4
LIMIT 1
```

I tried experimenting with the `primary_key` and `foreign_key` options, but they seem to be ignored completely in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be as simple as pie:

```rb
module Portal
  class Account < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name_prefix = 'portal.'

    # new relation:
    has_one :profile, foreign_key: :portal_account_id
  end
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_one(
    :portal_item,
    class_name: 'Portal::Item',
    foreign_key: :external_product_id,
    dependent: :restrict_with_exception,
  )

  # new relation:
  has_one(
    :portal_item_account,
    through: :portal_item,
    class_name: 'Portal::Account',
    source: :assignable,
    source_type: 'Account',
  )
  has_one(
    :portal_item_profile,
    through: :portal_item_account,
    source: :profile,
  )
end
```